# Authentication with multiple logins for Aerobatic / Bitbucket static site

Tags: bitbucket, jekyll, basic-authentication, static-site

I have a Jekyll static site hosted with Aerobatic / Bitbucket. I would like to have one page (/download) with links to pdf documents, which should be accessible to certain visitors only.

Aerobatic allows [password-protect some pages](https://aerobatic.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7471115), but I wonder if it is possible to

1. have multiple logins/passwords for one page and
2. protect all nested documents (/download/manual.pdf) with the same password as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Aerobatic HTTP basic auth only supports a single username/password. If you want a full blown membership solution, you might look at incorporating a service like Auth0. However this works best with a single page application rather than a traditional static set of html files.

As for protecting nested documents, Aerobatic auth does support that. For example if you want to protect only the `/downloads` section of your website, you could declare the basic-auth plugin like so:

```
{
 "module": "basic-auth",
 "path": "/downloads",
 "options": {
   "username": "${USERNAME}",
   "password": "${PASSWORD}"
 }
}
```

This should work for nested .pdf documents. See the docs for more details:

https://www.aerobatic.com/docs/http-basic-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the first question.

But regarding nested documents, I can't make it work. I do have plugin declared exactly as you suggested. Authentication dialog box opens if I try to go to /downloads or /downloads/blah-blah -- correct.
But when I try /downloads/manual.pdf it opens without dialog box. Manual.pdf is stored in folder /downloads under _site.